# how to hide links in a aspx repeater and get dataitem

Tags: asp.net

i am tring to get into repeater to hide button based on the deal status column 
but having trouble getting to that dataItem.dealstatus to check for comparison

here is what i have in the code behind

```
protected void myrepeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {


             if (e.Item.DataItem.DealStatus == "Sale Pending")
            {
               e.Item.FindControl("LinkDownloads").Visible = false;
            }

             if (e.Item.DataItem.DealStatus == "Quote")
             {
                  e.Item.FindControl("LinkDownloads").Visible = false;
                  e.Item.FindControl("LinkPurchase").Visible = false;
             }

        }
```

[image]

and here is my repeater code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SearchRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCreated="myrepeater_ItemCreated">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                                <td class="sorting_1"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DealId")%>' OnClick="OnClickCust" ><%#Eval("FullName")%></asp:LinkButton> </td>
                                                <td class=""><%#Eval("Year")%> <%#Eval("Make")%> <%#Eval("Model")%></td>
                                                <td class=""><%#Eval("Vin")%></td>
                                                <td class=""><%#Eval("Dt")%></td>
                                                <td class=""><%#Eval("DealStatus")%></td>
                                                <td class="">

                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="PlanButton" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DealID")%>'  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block plan" runat="server" OnClick="LinkPlan_OnClickkPlan_OnClick">Plan</asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkPurchase" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block purchase" runat="server">Purchase</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkDownloads" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block downloads" runat="server">Downloads</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>    
                                  </asp:Repeater>
```

here is that answer

```
object DI = e.Item.DataItem;
string status = DataBinder.Eval(DI, "DealStatus").ToString();
```

Comment: You say you're having trouble, but you don't say what you're having trouble with. Are you getting an exception? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using a lable instead.
Inside the repeater

```
 <asp:Label ID="DealStatus_Lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DealStatus") %>' />
```

Code Behing

```
Label lblA = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("DealStatus_Lbl");
If(lbla.Text== )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.Item.DataItem` always returns an object in your case. Therefore `e.Item.DataItem.DealStatus` won't work. Usually you have to cast the object to its constituent item. And that item depends on what you have bound your repeater with...

For e.g. if its a list of person objects, where each person object has say name and age as properties, you'd do something like:

```
var person = (Person)e.Item.DataItem;
var name = person.name;
```

If its a list of name (i.e. a simple `List<string>`), then e.Item.DataItem would represent a single string object. Hence:

```
var name = (string) e.Item.DataItem;
```

Most people learn what that constituent object is through debugging only. So no worries there. Just bind the repeater to a datatable and find the type of e.Item.DataItem to see what I mean. :)

There is nothing vehemently wrong with your solution, but if you want to work with the item in a type safe and a relatively efficient manner I'd try to cast it to my workable object first, and then consume it.

Moreover, say that object has two or more properties, it isn't wise to call `DataBinder.Eval` multiple times to fetch all property values, since each call incurs the overhead of reflection.

Update: The event arguments will only be populated with the DataItem only on the databound event, i.e the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: ok i have tried to do it the way you have it  i am getting                var dealstatus = (DealStatus)e.Item.DataItem;
                var deal = dealstatus.DealStatus;     but i get  a NullReferenceException

Comment: You can debug and see the type: `e.Item.DataItem.GetType().Name` . Break somewhere in the event call. and type it in the Immediate Window. And I hope you are doing it during ItemDataBound event...

Comment: ok so let me be clear i forgot to explain some thing the way i have it is working except when i click on one of the buttons it does a post back and that is when i get the null exception error and your solution did not work

Comment: What was your intent of handling the ItemCreated event?